# How to prevent Smarty secure_mode activation?

Tags: email, smarty

I hope my silly question will get answers from some of you...

I'm just trying to send an email using smarty basics functions such as using {php} tags and playing php in smarty tags {if strstr($email, '@')}.

But each time I try to send the template Smarty activate secure_mode and everything's ruined...

I found where Smarty put the secure_mode but I can't understand why... (in CRM/Core/Smarty.php line 202).

If someone ever run into this and solved it pleeeease help me  :'(

PS : I defined this in my settings file => define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 );

Still working on it !

I hope i'll find the solution  ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing arbitrary php to be executed from an email string can potentially cause security issues from un-trusted users and hence the security mode of smarty is enabled for all string based resources.

I dont think there is an easy work-around for this :(

Comment: Thank's for your answer I will try with Smarty functions alone